# Center image not working?

Tags: html, css, center, centering

I'm probably turning mad but I really cannot seem to find out what I'm doing wrong. I'm simply trying to center my image.

```
<div class="container ">
    <img src="design/images/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo" />
    <div class="contactData">
        data
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.container {
    max-width: 978px;
    width: calc(100% - 46px);
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 23px;
    padding-right: 23px;

.logo {
        width: 337px;
        height: 76px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        float: none;
    }

 .contactData {
        max-width: 206px;
        margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        float: none;
  }
```

The contactData div just centers fine but the image doesn't.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle.net?

Comment: `calc` doesn't work so well...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add `display:block;` in your `.logo`

That should probably fix it

Answer (score 2):

Use either `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;` while you are using `margin: auto;` for the images.

```
.logo {
    width: 337px;
    height: 76px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: none;
    display: block;
}
```

Images are `inline` by default and you need to trigger `hasLayout` or something similar.

Comment: I have a question regarding this. When I set the display to block, it works, but then I set it to inline-block it doesn't center the image anymore. Is there a way to set my margin (for example a margin-top) while using the block property?

Comment: When you are setting it to `inline-block` it acts as a text. So, margins won't work. Setting `margin: 15px auto 0` is something like you are setting top margin as `15px` and centering it and no bottom margin.

Comment: if you use `inline-block`, than add `text-align:center;`

Comment: Adding text-align:center; does not change anything unfortunately. :(

Comment: `text-align: center` with `display: inline-block` will do the magic.

Comment: You have to add `text-align:center` to the `.container` and the `display:inline-block;` to `.logo` Thats the other way to do it. But I prefer adding `display:block; margin: 0 auto;` in `.logo` because thats keeps the code just before the image. If you add thr `text-align:center` to the container div. It will center all text elements in your container div.

Answer (score 0):

add this code

```
.container {
    max-width: 978px;
    width: calc(100% - 46px);
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 23px;
    padding-right: 23px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
```

Comment: Though this is one of the solutions but everything will be in center along with images!

Answer (score 0):

In `.logo` just add `display:block;` in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying any aligning for image.
In the container class, Just give

```
text-align:center;
```

Comment: Did you try?. Because I tested it and works just fine. @2339870

Comment: @2339870[See this jsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/smashitjusty/7LvAY/1/) .                                                        Try removing the text-align:center from container class. You will see the difference.